# How do I insert line numbers in vim (or sed) if I want to skip some lines?

Tags: vim, sed

I'm working with a markdown file in vim, and I want to number the lines. To insert the line numbers is easy:

```
:%s/^/\=printf('%-4d', line('.'))
```

But there's a hitch. I want to ignore any and all header lines (##Header) and still keep the numbers sequential. That means I can't simply insert the actual line number. Ignoring leading hashtags is no problem, but I can't figure out how to maintain an accurate count.

Comment: You're right, I should have done that. But the answers below do a nice job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be difficult to achieve it with `vim` or `sed` because they do not
have a `variable` which can be modified depending on the condition.
If `awk` is your option, would you please try:

```
awk '!/^#/ {$0 = sprintf("%-4d", ++n) $0} 1' file.md > file_new.md
```

An input file `file.md` looks like:

```
# Header 1
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
### Header 2
sit
amet
```

Then the output `file_new.md` will be:

```
# Header 1
1   Lorem
2   ipsum
3   dolor
### Header 2
4   sit
5   amet
```

- The condition `!/^#/` is satisfied if the line *does not* start with '#'
  then the following `{...}` block is evaluated.
- The statement `$0 = sprintf("%-4d", ++n) $0` prepends a concecutive
  number to the line (only if the condition above is met).
- The final `1` tells `awk` to print current line regardless of the condition.

Answer (score 1):

The following Vim command works in my limited testing:

```
:let i = 0 | v/^#/let i += 1 | s/^/\=i . ' '
```

Generalities:

- `|` marks the separation between two Ex commands.
- `g/<pattern>/<command>` executes `<command>` on every line matching `<pattern>`.
- `v/<pattern>/<command>` does the same on every line *not* matching `<pattern>`.
- When using `:help :g` or `:help :v`, it is important to know that *everything* that comes after the second `/`, including `|`, is part of `<command>` so:

  ```
  :g/foo/cmd1 | cmd2
  ```

  won't do `g/foo/cmd1` then `cmd2`. Instead, it will do `cmd1` and `cmd2` on each matching line.

Specifics:

- `:let i = 0` initiates an iterator with value `0`,
- `v/^#/…` will execute the remainder of the command on every line not starting with `#`,
- `let i += 1` increments the iterator,
- `s/^/\=i . ' '` prepends the current line with the current value of the iterator followed by a space. `:help \=` is used in the replacement part because it allows us to use an expression, and thus consume variables.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU  nl):

```
nl -bp'^[^#]\|^$' file
```

Will line number all lines except those non-empty lines beginning with `#`.